# xCode exclude watchkit extension for submitting

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, watchkit, build-settings

I wrote an app using watchkit and wanted to submit it yesterday after Apple releases iOS 8.2. Unfortunately I got to know here on stackoverflow, that apps using watchkit are not allowed to be submitted yet...

I do think that my app is also good as a standalone iPhone app and would like to submit the watchkit part as an update as soon as it's possible.

What is the best way to exclude the watch extension from my archive I want to submit? I don't want to build up a whole new project if possible.

I tried unchecking the "Target Membership" of the Extension.appex in my products folder. I then got this error:
[image: error]

How can I exclude the watch extension the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to exclude the WatchKit extension from your app, you just need to remove their targets from the targets list in your project. And remove their related files and groups.

Comment: To bad there is no other way. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I honestly don't think so. Because on their website they are saying Apps targeted iOS 8.2 and hight SDKs are not accepted.

Comment: There is an easier way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426501/prevent-deploying-disable-watchkit-app-with-ios-iphone-app-in-xcode