# How to remove apple Watch app from existing Xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, apple-watch

I add a watch app target to my project. How can I undo this?

I remove Watch target and scheme already. But it's show alert message "install app failed" on my apple watch when i debug my ios app project.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In Xcode 6.3.2, **two** steps are necessary:

- Remove the WatchKit extension from "Target Dependencies"
- Remove WatchKit extension from "Embed App Extensions"

A detailed description is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426501/prevent-deploying-disable-watchkit-app-with-ios-iphone-app-in-xcode).