# WatchKit - iOS App Bundle Contains 2 WatchKit App Binaries

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch

[image]

When I build my iOS app for the app store and run the validation, I see that the embedded binaries and entitlements section contains two instances of my watchkit app. How is this happening? Has anyone else faced this problem?

The entitlements I use are for keychain sharing and app group sharing.

If any more information is needed, I'll be glad to provide it. When I build an enterprise version of this app and distribute it to my team, only one WatchKit app is installed. Should this be OK to submit to Apple then?

Comment: Check the main app, at the bottom of the general tab (when clicking the project and selecting the target), is the WatchKit app embedded twice?

Comment: I checked. The .appex binary is only embedded once.