# Is there a way to disable my app's Watch app without removing it from the project?

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

I want to make a public release without the Watch app (which should only be released with TestFlight releases).

Answer (score 4):

[Here is how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426501/prevent-deploying-disable-watchkit-app-with-ios-iphone-app-in-xcode)

Basically, you just need to take 2 steps in "Build Phases" of you main target:

1. Remove the WatchOS extension from "Target Dependencies"
2. Remove WatchOS app from "Embed Watch Content"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking this a step further: Create a new target as a duplicate of your application's target and call it TestFlight. You can do this by right-clicking on your application target under the General tab for the project. This way you can configure your build dependencies independently from your normal AppStore release builds. Then, as ajpallares mentioned, remove the apple watch targets from your target dependencies under Build Phases.