# Apple Watch App Extension won't run on the simulator anymore

Tags: watchos-2

I'm creating my first Apple Watch app and upon first adding the Watch and Watch extension targets I was able to start building my interface and running on the simulator. Since then I've needed to update my iOS app while still working on the Watch app. So I used this advice to "disable" my watch app so I could submit a build for the new iOS version:

[Prevent deploying (disable) WatchKit App with iOS iPhone App in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426501/prevent-deploying-disable-watchkit-app-with-ios-iphone-app-in-xcode)

Simply, by removing the watch and extension in target dependencies and embedded watch content in Build Phases did the trick. Now I'm picking back up the work I put down but can't seem to get it to run on the simulator. I add back the target dependencies and the embedded watch content but I get the error: Error Launching 'App Name Extension' Invalid Bundle - No Apple Watch Binary

Can anyone explain what that means and why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this problem seeking an answer. I found that I had been changing my version and build number to accommodate my current iPhone version and build number. This was creating that error, so to fix it I left the watch app and extension app version/build as default 1.0 and 1.

[image: Version and Buikld]