# Adding WatchApp Extension Back To iOS Target Not Working

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-watch

I recently removed my WatchKit extension from my iOS Target so I could publish a build on the App Store w/out the Watch App; however, since I've tried to add it back, it's not working anymore. I have followed the steps from this question (to remove & add back) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426501/prevent-deploying-disable-watchkit-app-with-ios-iphone-app-in-xcode), and my app compiles and builds, but the Watch Connectivity feature does not work anymore. I changed my build number/version on the iOS Target, so I also changed it on the Watch App, but whenever I update the value on my iPhone, it does not transmit the data to my watch anymore. What are all of the steps required to add a watch app back into the iPhone target if you've removed it? Thanks!

I can post code; however, all I know is that it was working fine (transmitting/updating data on the watch) before I removed it, and has since stopped working it after adding it back

Comment: If it worked in the past but isn't working the same now, yet the code hasn't changed, something has probably changed with the SDK or OS in the meantime.  What version of iOS/watchOS did it work under? Have you upgraded Xcode or your watch or phone OS in the meantime?

Comment: I think it was under the Embedded Binaries/etc.; I didn't change the code, OS for the watch or phone, or Xcode. I'm not sure if maybe I didn't add it back correctly